# Increasing font size in TexShop 4.3

Tags: texshop

I'm running TexShop 4.3 on OSX 10.14.1. The key combination `⌘+` would increase the font size in my editor but it hasn't been working in the last few releases. I also tried `⌘<shift>+` but that doesn't help either. In TexShop's menu under `Source` -> `Font` -> Bigger has the symbol `⌘=` next to it. Anyone know the right keystrokes to increase/decrease font size in the editor?

Comment: You have to select the text and then increase the size

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say this is a “hidden feature”. In version 4.23 the behavior is the same: when pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>, nothing happens *unless* the first character in the document is selected (with any number of following characters). The same for <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> for decreasing the font size.

Similarly, if the focus is on the editing window and you press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, doing a choice in the font window that appears has no effect, unless the first character is selected.

This font setting is not permanent and will be lost when closing the window.

#### Update 2022

The feature, as of version 5.04, is no longer hidden: if you press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>, the font will grow bigger whether or not something is selected. However the setting is not persistent.

With <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> the standard macOS font panel will appear and one can set the editor font as preferred, but just for the current editor window and the setting is not remembered through editing sessions.

The default font for the editor window can be set in the Source tab of the Preferences.

Comment: This is bad news, I'm deprecating TeXShop and choosing an older version to avoid this.

Comment: "Hidden"?! I see no reason to hide this feature. Does anyone have any context on this?

Comment: @k-dubs That was understatement for “bug”.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the source font size permanently is possible if you follow the answer I got by Richard Koch. Here it is:

Go to TeXShop Preferences, and under the Source tab the first item is Document Font. Push the "Set" button.
Two things happen. A Small window comes up showing you some sample text, and the font panel comes up. DO
NOT CLICK OK in the sample yet.

Using the font panel, select the font and size you like. The sample will change, showing the new results. When you are happy, click OK in the sample. And then, click OK at the bottom of the preference dialog.

Comment: Re Volker's explanation: I wonder how the "font panel" comes up. Nothing happens for me in TeXShop but the Sample text panel covers the whole Source panel (almost) and I cannot change the editor font at all.

Comment: I had to click "set" multiple times before the font windows popped up.  Not sure if that's a but.

Answer (score 2):

(I am using TeXShop in a brand new MacTeX 2020 installation and felt the answers here were not clear, so I decided to post a new answer.)

Open TeXShop. Go to TeXShop--->Preferences--->Source. Under Document Font, click Set.... A box called Sample Text and a box called Fonts appear. You need to delete all the text in the Sample Text box first. Then select the font you want in the Font box. Now type some text in the now empty Sample Text box (empty because you just deleted the text). Click OK in the Sample Text box. Then click OK again to close the menu.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you add please some screenshots of your used menu points to your answer?