# Changing font size for input window in TexShop

Tags: texshop

My old eyes can't read the font in the input window.  How can I change the font size?  Under Preferences,  there is a Set font type and size, but it's not changeable.[image]

Comment: Does this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472021/increasing-font-size-in-texshop-4-3) give you an answer for your question?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE!

Answer (score 1):

Click the `Set...` button and a font selection window will appear.

[image: macOS font panel in TeXShop]

On the right hand side of that window, you can change the size of the current font either by selecting a fixed size or by moving the vertical slider. Adjust the size to your needs, and then click the `OK` button in the TeXShop Preferences window. You will also need to dismiss the font selection window by clicking on the red button in its upper left hand corner.